# How do I Create a For Loop that checks if a column contains duplicates in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, duplicates

I'm trying to create a `for` loop that first check checks if a column (`'col1'`) has duplicates and if true add the value from another column (`'col2'`) to the (`'col1'`).

The below statement works however, all (`'col1'`) values are being treated as duplicates. I'm sure there are actually very few duplicates in the column but somehow the statement keeps returning true. I think the problem lies in the second line the one containing `.duplicated()`

```
import pandas as pd

tuple = [['Jake','NY'],['Tom','Montana'],['Hannah','Cali'],['Jason','Boston'],['Tom','Washington'],['Hannah','Florida']]

df = pd.DataFrame(tuple, columns=('col1', 'col2'))

for i in df['col1']:
        if df['col1'].duplicated().any():
                df['col1'] = df['col1'] + ' - ' +  df['col2']
```

Comment: Can you please provide part of your data frame and your desired output?

Comment: This is actually not using your `for` loop at all. It's just repeating the same operation multiple times.

Comment: I do not mean your code. Just a pseudo data frame like `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3})` etc.. It would be quite helpful for the sake of transparency and reproducibility

Comment: My apologies I'm new to python and stackoverflow. I've typed the code above as an example that you can run on your systems. I believe the fix written by @Paul works. But I'm still confused as to how my first code would not work

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicate values the using duplicated as you showed in your example, this can be used as a filter using `loc`:

`df.loc[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False), 'col1']`

You can use this to replace these values with a new value:

```
temp = df['col1'] + ' - ' + df['col2']
df.loc[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False), 'col1'] = temp
```

##### UPDATE

With example from OP:

```
import pandas as pd
tuple = [['Jake','NY'],['Tom','Montana'],['Hannah','Cali'], ['Jason','Boston'],['Tom','Washington'],['Hannah','Florida']]
df = pd.DataFrame(tuple, columns=('col1', 'col2'))
temp = df['col1'] + ' - ' + df['col2']
df.loc[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False), 'col1'] = temp
df
```

```
col1                col2
Jake                NY
Tom - Montana       Montana
Hannah - Cali       Cali
Jason               Boston
Tom - Washington    Washington
Hannah - Florida    Florida
```